# A movie about relationship between a young man and his stepsister

Tags: identify-this-movie

I'm looking for a 2000's drama movie about a sexual relationship between a young man and his step sister. It was an usa made movie. I watched it 3 years ago so it could be from 2002-2013. Also it was a low budget and probably low rated movie.

The young man was about 20-22 age. He was short, around 5' 7'' or 1.70 m tall, had bronze skin, black short hair and dark eyes. His haircut was formal, military i guess. He was driving a truck and trying to find his father's address in a small town. His father and mother were seperated many years ago and he couldn't contact him after that. Either he was back from the service or military academy. I'm not sure but he could have a sister also, but she wasn't with him while he was searching.

One day he finally found his dad and talked to him. His house was in the suburbs in a little town. He talked to his father and he said that he divorced with his mother many years ago and he had no more responbility to him. He also said that he had married again and had a girl from this marriage. He was living with his new family and he didn't want to deal with his ex-marriage. He was much tall from his son, white, had grey hair and about 50-55 age.

The young man got angry after this conversation and his father's attitude. He decided to take revenge from him. His father had a girl aged 16-18 and he tried to be a friend with her. She was blonde, a lttle bit skinny, had a lovely voice and liked singing. She was an infant teacher or volunteer at a kindergarten.

They started to dating. It was a small town so they've not got much place to go. One day they went on a riverside and got off the truck. It was very quite and there were only sound of nature. She was drawing and singing. He was looking at her and thinking. He didn't fallen love with her but he decided to take her virginity to get revenge from his father. He kissed her and then they had sex.

The genre was drama and there were too much slow songs in the soundtrack. I was watching it after midnight and i couldn't resist to sleeping so i couldn't watch the rest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [The King (2005)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0396688/?ref_=kw_li_tt), starring Gael Garcia Bernal as the young man, William Hurt as the estranged father (a pastor), and Pell James as the teenage daughter.

> Elvis leaves the Navy and heads for Texas where he contacts his father, whom he's never met, the pastor at a Christian community church. Pastor Dave tells Elvis to stay away and, without telling his family that Elvis is his son from a pre-conversion liaison, tells them to have nothing to do with him. But Elvis has already connected with Malerie, the pastor's 16-year old daughter. Elvis embarks on the seduction of Malerie, while Dave examines his conscience and comes to a new conclusion. Can anyone get right with the Lord? Does the Lord hear?

Comment: Yes, correct answer thank you. By the way i had no idea that he was Gael Garcia Bernal with that haircut !